# SOAP web services client with ExtJS, SOAP and JavaScript

Tags: extjs, soap

I implemented SOAP web services with WildFly. Invocation of endpoint interface is successful. The below url returns the correct result.

http://localhost:8080/SOAPJaxbWeb/?operation=ICallMemberPort

But the ExtJS soap client does not work at all. These are my ExtJS soap client codes.

```
Ext.define('Member', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [{
        name : 'id',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'passwd',
        type : 'string'
    }, {
        name : 'age',
        type : 'int'
    }, {
        name : 'name',
        type : 'string'
    }]
});

Ext.onReady(function () {

    var family = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store' , {

        model : 'Member',
        autoLoad : true,
        proxy: {
            type: 'soap',
            url: 'SOAPJaxbWeb/',
            api: {
                read: 'ICallMemberPort'
            },
            soapAction: {
                read: 'http://localhost:8080/SOAPJaxbWeb/?operation=ICallMemberPort'
            },
            operationParam: 'ICallMemberPort',
            targetNamespace: 'http://www.aaa.com/',
            reader: {
                type: 'soap',
                record: 'ns|return',
                namespace: 'ns'
            },
            exception: function(proxy, response, operation){
                Ext.MessageBox.show({
                    title: 'REMOTE EXCEPTION',
                    msg: operation.getError(),
                    icon: Ext.MessageBox.ERROR,
                    buttons: Ext.Msg.OK
                });
            }
        },

        listeners: {
            load: function(family, operation, success) {
                if(success) {
                    alert('response : ' + family.model.length)
                } else {
                    alert('it failed')
                }
            }
        }

    });

    var onButtonClick = function() {
        Ext.Msg.alert(Ext.getCmp('myid').getValue())
        family.load()
    };
```

I am afraid above ExtJS soap configuration is wrong. When executed, nothing shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

proxy: soap

Note: This functionality is only available with the purchase of Sencha Complete. For more information about using this class, please visit our Sencha Complete product page.

https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-classic/#!/api/Ext.data.soap.Proxy